# Toggleclass reversing on children and grandchildren of unordered list

Tags: jquery

I'm using a Wordpress PHP function to create a header menu for my theme. When the screen is at mobile width I have configured it to take on a push/slide menu layout, in which the submenus are activated by little buttons to the right of parent list items. I am using my jQuery to select all `li`and `li a`items that are children of parent list items, then using the toggleClass function to add the additional class `.open`.

A problem that I am facing now is that when travelling down the DOM, the children of the parent list items have their toggle class order reversed. The first layer of list items are fine, but the second layer (grandchildren, so to speak) are transitioning the wrong way round.

I have recreated the effects of this issue in a jsfiddle, in which I have added background and text colors to demonstrate the problem more clearly. A point worth noting is that the `ul` items seem to be okay – for example in the jsfiddle they're supposed to start off white and then turn green. It's the `li` and `li a` items that start reversing on the third level of the menu.

Is there a way in which I can select all of the elements within the unordered list structure – i.e  `ul` `li` and `li a` individually and give them their own toggleClass command?

https://jsfiddle.net/8nj5y4t1/34/

**HTML:**

(please note that on my actual Wordpress theme, the menus are configured via PHP and aren't hard coded, so I can't use classes to target them.

```
<nav class="main-menu" id="mobile">
    <div class="menu-header-menu-container">
        <ul id="menu-header-menu-1" class="menu">
            <li class="hide-desktop menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1386"><a href="http://www.mywebsite.com">Home</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-463"><a href="http://www.mywebsite.comwork/">Work</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-584"><a href="http://www.mywebsite.comwork/landscapes/">Landscapes</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-473"><a href="http://www.mywebsite.comwork/seascapes/">Seascapes</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-478"><a href="http://www.mywebsite.comwork/macro/">Macro</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-477"><a href="http://www.mywebsite.comwork/cities/">Cities</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-475"><a href="http://www.mywebsite.comwork/long-exposure/">Long Exposure</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-480"><a href="http://www.mywebsite.comwork/miscellaneous/">Miscellaneous</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-2 current_page_item menu-item-has-children menu-item-10"><a href="http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/about/">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-464"><a href="http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/shop/">Shop</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14"><a href="http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/contact/">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
nav.main-menu#mobile {
  min-width:300px;
  max-width:400px;
  background-color:orange;
  padding-top:20px;
  padding-bottom:20px;
}

nav.main-menu#mobile ul { 
    position:relative; 
    overflow: auto; 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

nav.main-menu#mobile ul li {
    display:inline-block; 
    float:left; 
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}

nav.main-menu#mobile ul li a {
    display:inline-block;
    height: auto;
    width: 200px;
    padding:15px 0px 15px 30px;
    font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica;
    font-size: 18px;
    color:purple;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.submenu-button {
    cursor:pointer;
    float:right;
    padding:15px 20px 15px 20px;
}

nav.main-menu#mobile ul ul {
    max-height:0;
    width:100%;
    transition: all 800ms;
    background-color:white;
    overflow:hidden;
}

nav.main-menu#mobile ul ul.open { 
    max-height:1000px;
    background-color:green;
}

nav.main-menu#mobile ul ul li {
    transition:2s;
}

nav.main-menu#mobile ul ul li a {
    padding-left: 45px;
    font-size: 16px;
    transition:2s;
}

nav.main-menu#mobile ul ul li a.open {
    color:yellow;
}

nav.main-menu#mobile ul ul ul {
    background-color:white;
}

nav.main-menu#mobile ul ul ul.open {
    background-color:green;
}

nav.main-menu#mobile ul ul ul li a {
    padding-left:60px;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('<span class="submenu-button">+</span>').insertBefore('nav.main-menu#mobile ul li:not(.hide-mobile) ul').parent('li');

    $('.submenu-button').click(function() {
        $(this).next().toggleClass('open').find('li, li > a').toggleClass('open');

    });

});
```

Comment: Like this?  https://jsfiddle.net/8nj5y4t1/35/

Comment: Yes, that worked perfectly thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `children()` as `find()` will look for all descendants but children only includes immediate descendents

```
  $('.submenu-button').click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggleClass('open').children('li').toggleClass('open');    
  });
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/8nj5y4t1/35/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, I read about the `children()` value a while ago but I couldn't get it to work when I tried it – I think I was trying to specify `li` `li a` etc within the brackets rather than leaving them blank. So am I correct in thinking that this will carry on working for an infinite number of child menus should I wish to add them, with the `toggleClass` function working the correct way round? (i.e not reversing)

Comment: Well one thing to consider is what would be expected behavior of sub menu that is open when a higher level that contains it is closed. But should work at multiple levels yes

Comment: Ah – so if later down the line, I want to make it so that when I open a first and second level of the menu, the second level closes when I close the first, would I run into problems with the `children()` selector?

Comment: No but would take more conditional logic

Comment: Hi charlietfl, sorry to bother you again – I've just realised that now it's only the `ul` menu that's being given the additional class `.open`. The `li`and `li a` aren't being given this class. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: target is the `li`. Don't see why you need the class on `<a>` also and not just use css rule based on `li.open a` selector

Comment: I wanted to change the text color – at the moment this only affects the first one for some reason. https://jsfiddle.net/8nj5y4t1/40/

Comment: You added extra code that doesn't make sense. Works fine here https://jsfiddle.net/8nj5y4t1/42/

Comment: Ah yes, it works. Thank you for taking the time to explain that.